# Using Mocha features in Karma?

Tags: mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm unit testing my Javascript (AngularJS) app using Karma, Mocha and Chai. This all works fine, however in Mocha's doc I see a lot of cool stuff like custom reporters and text diffs on failures. How can I use these features when not using Mocha directly but trough karma-mocha?

As an example, how could I use Mocha's "Landing Strip" reporter instead of Karma's default "dots" or "progress" reporters?

Comment: If you are using Karma, unless you run the mocha tests in another environment as well, I guess you have to look at a karma reporter rather than a mocha one.